# Rails: can a model have no attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord, model

I currently have two models, `User` and `Company`. I'm thinking of making a 3rd model that would act as a parent to the other two, and it would be like this:

```
Account
 - Company
 -- User(s)
```

The only problem I see with this is that I can't decide whether this model *needs* any attributes besides an ID.

Is it possible or even useful to have a model that theoretically has no attributes, other than its ID?

Comment: You can, but the question is, how you will *identify* any account except from it's ID and how can you establish the relationship implicitly.

Comment: Its a good question -- I wonder what other developers do for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am not from rails background.** But it's like general question from data modelling.

**So Ofcourse yes. You can have an object without attributes.**

It will be useful to query the certain `Account` as you modelled. Even If you don't have any attributes, you still have a `relationship` with `Company`. So no worries. Go ahead.

**An Object without any attribute and relationships is useless. But you have relationship. So it is still useful in its way.**